# Why $\phi$ $\cdot$ R = $\phi$, rather than $\phi$ $\cdot$ R = R in Automata?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammars

I understand that $\phi$ is a null symbol.
why concatenation of any language L with $\phi$ is $\phi$ rather than L ?

Comment: Try using the definition of concatenation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us check the definition.

For two sets of strings $S_1$ and $S_2$, the concatenation $S_1\cdot S_2$ consists of all strings of the form $vw$ where $v$ is a string from $S_1$ and $w$ is a string from $S_2$, or formally $S_1\cdot S_2 = \{ vw : v \in S_1, w \in S_2 \}$.

What about $\emptyset\cdot R$?

Since there is no string in the empty set, we cannot find any string of that form $vw$ where $v$ is a string from the empty set. For example, you cannot form a mixed double in tennis if there is no male players. So $\emptyset\cdot R=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably confusing $\emptyset$, the langauge that contains no strings at all, with $\{\varepsilon\}$, the language that contains only the empty string.